# EF7 Migrations - The corresponding CLR type for entity type '' is not instantiable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use EF7 migrations and got stuck when I modeled an `Organization` model with inheritance.

`Organization` is an abstract class. There are two concrete classes that inherit from it called `Individual` and `Company`.

I set the `Organization` abstract class as `DbSet<Organization>` in `DbContext` and run migrations.

I'm following this tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

The following error is shown:

> The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'Organization' is not instantiable and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type.

Whats should I do?

**EDIT - Updated with code.**

**Organization:**

```
public abstract class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {
        ChildOrganizations = new HashSet<Organization>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public bool PaymentNode { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    // virtual
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> ChildOrganizations { get; set; }
}
```

**Individual**

```
public class Individual : Organization
{
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

**Company**

```
public class Company : Organization
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class CoreDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Organization> Organization { get; set; }

    public CoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<CoreDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add code in the question.

Comment: Do you have the DbContext in the same project or in a seperate project?

Comment: @TomDroste DbContext is in same class library project as the domain models and migrations are in web project.

Comment: Then there lies your problem. Will place my answer with the reason and a workaround shortly

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

> If you don’t want to expose a DbSet for one or more entities in the hierarchy, you can use the Fluent API to ensure they are included in the model.

If you don't want to have to create a `DbSet` for each subclass then you have to explicitly define them in the `OnModelCreating` override of the `DbContext`:

```
public class CoreDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Organization> Organization { get; set; }

    public CoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<CoreDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Individual>();
        builder.Entity<Company>();

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'll try that out!

Comment: Your link is broken now.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Fixed the link. I found an archive of the old link and it contained mostly the same information. You can view that here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160827200902/http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/inheritance.html

Comment: In the updated documentation it says to use `HasBaseType`. I don't know if that means the original behavior is no longer valid. I will update the answer if anyone can confirm otherwise.

Comment: @JoelMcBeth I just checked, original behavior is still working in EF Core 5.0.2.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work for me. :< Still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 21):

In case anyone makes a stupid mistake like me, My entity was abstract. So maybe check if you have mistakenly made the same issue.

Comment: This is mentioned by OP and is a deliberate choice, so it's not a "mistake" and removing the abstract part is not the fix.

Comment: @EarthMind Some answers are for other people. Especially considering this answer was posted some 4 years after the question was resolved.

Comment: Wow ! @Manzur is my man ! He made my day - I did same crappy mistake- forgetting to remove the abstract keyword.
Thanx for sharing ! ++Manzur :D

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the tutorial you linked, your `DbSet<>` properties should be the inheriting `Individual` and `Company`classes.

Try having your `CoreDbContext` look more like this:

```
public class CoreDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Individual> Individuals { get; set; }

    public CoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<CoreDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: In EF6, according to this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

You can define the DbSet using the base class. Doing the same thing in EF Core doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should also put in your `CoreDbContext` class the classes that inherit Organization. Then it will discriminate and instantiate those objects correctly. It should look like this:

```
public DbSet<Organization> Organization { get; set; }
public DbSet<Individual> Individual { get; set; }
public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you use a `class library` project. In RC2 of EF Core you can't place your DBContext in such a project. This is a known issue. When you convert it to a 'app' project it should work again.

**More info & source:**

Workaround: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-cli-issues

Github issue:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5460

Comment: This is not the case. I had this issue in the past and solved it as written in the links you posted. I've used migrations successfully but now when i use inheritance it throws the error I provided earlier in my description. It seems that the issue is with TPT ( Table per type ) See link: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt