# EntityFrameworkCore and "variant" navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have following model, which (quite rightfully) does not work with Entity Framework Core. My problem is that I don't see an elegant solution right now, but I am sure this is a simple and quite generic construct, so I would appreciate a kick in the right direction.

Please see comments in the code for additional requirements that I have.

```
public abstract class Parent  // requirement: must stay abstract
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Father : Parent
    { 
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mother : Parent
    {
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }

    public class Book
    { 
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Parent Owner { get; set; } // Requirement: single Owner property; can be of Mother or Father Type
    }

    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Mother> Mothers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Father> Fathers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Father>()
                .HasMany(s => s.Books)
                .WithOne(s => (Father)s.Owner); // This was just an try

            builder.Entity<Mother>()
                .HasMany(s => s.Books)
                .WithOne(s => (Mother)s.Owner); // This was just an try

            builder.Entity<Book>()
                .HasKey(t => t.Id); 
  
        }

    }
```

Add-Migration does not go though with the message:

```
The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'Parent' cannot be instantiated, and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type.
```

I thought so far of these potential solutions, but none qualifying:

1. Making Parent an Entity and moving the `List<Book> Books` there => No go
2. Giving up on navigation from Book to Owner => also No go
3. Splitting the Book class into two separate classes (e.g. FemaleBook & MaleBook) and managing two Entities instead of one. Very undesirable and leading to effectively doubling the code of the app => No go
4. A generic class? `Book<Father>, Book<Mother>`. Not sure, but I think that would also end up with two distinct Entities as of 3.
5. Something else you can help me with :-)

**Remark**: All classes have domain behavior methods which were omitted here for brevity. Father's a Mother's are unique (mix of override of Parent's and newly introduced).

PS: The app I am working on has nothing to do with Mothers, Fathers and Books. Just tried to provide minimum code example.

Many thanks for help.

Comment: Just don't use inheritance. Give `Parent` a type field and inject behavior at runtime by a behavioral pattern based on composition (f.e. *strategy*).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398141/ef7-migrations-the-corresponding-clr-type-for-entity-type-is-not-instantiab) answer your question?

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, good and valid suggestion, but in this case I am trying to do the exact opposite - Refactoring towards more encapsulation, internal/private properties and no injected services (just in the very core domain assembly). I know didn't mention this in the post.

Comment: @Riwen Unfortunately it doesn't, it's close but all about problem I don't have.

Comment: This model is against relational database principles, hence cannot be mapped in EF (Core). The only valid option is #1, not sure why (what was the reason) you wrote "No go". Parent must be abstract entity with collection navigation property, and Father and Mother are concrete entities. All this configured as either TPH or TPT.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you! It is indeed the only viable option. I marked that option "No go" simply because I didn't get the TPH/TPT part. Now it's all fine, thanks again! EF (Core) is so great.